# Force Music app to sort with prefixes (“The”, “A”, “An”, etc.)

Tags: itunes, music.app, sip, sort

<del>Back in the ol'days</del> In iTunes package, there was a file called `SortPrefixes.plist` in localisation folders containing several sort prefixes (“The”, “A”, “An”, etc.). Removing them in this file was making iTunes to auto-sort everything including these prefixes (*The Chemical Brothers* was listed at T and not C).
(I have a *lot* of music files and I don't want to fix this by adding a *Sort Artist* to each of them.)

In the new Music app, there is no such file in Localisation folders, but I've just found a similar one in `/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AMPLibrary.framework/Versions/A/Resources/XX.lproj/SortPrefixes.strings`, containing the same samples of prefixes.

Since AMPLibraryAgent is managing libraries for Music.app and TV.app, I believe I might be on the right track and I'm tempted to clear them. But these files are stored in `/System/Library/` so I don't want to mess with the system: does it sound quite safe?
(It [doesn't look like](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22AMPLibrary.framework%22%20%22SortPrefixes.strings%22) a known trick yet.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than trying to coerce Music to do what it may not now support, you could try to use 'Artist to Last-First' from Dougscripts, and let the existing data work for you with a bit of automation.

https://dougscripts.com/itunes/scripts/ss.php?sp=mxartisttolastfirst

I've just given this a try and it works well, with minimal donation nag.

Comment: That's a great tips, thanks! Ideally I'd prefer leave the Sort fields blanks, but if there's no other option that might help… Or even just put the content of Artist in Sort Artist would do it.

Comment: I think long term, sort fields is the only solution for your problem @Joan

Comment: @bmike Does it sound like the OP would be better of experimenting rather than having to pay to re-gain functionality without a donation nag?

Comment: @AndrewMorton Given all the bugs and UX issues that are increasingly present in this app, I've given up trying to solve this kind of frustration and I think I'm learning to live with it. (I mean how can this be an Apple made software really?)

Comment: @Joan "how can this be an Apple made software" - they have a chance to make extra money if a third party has to supply software, via ~30%(?) to Apple in the App Store, to restore previous functionality.